# Checking if user typed text validation - while

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a piece of code that will ask the user for some text, (which I have so far) and if the user types in a number it asks for text again UNTIL the user types in text, not numbers.

```
            string input;
            int value;

            Console.WriteLine("Type in some text: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please type in some text without numbers");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(input); 
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I think it might be a while loop but not sure,

Any suggestion appreciated thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need a while loop. If you change your `if` to a `while` and remove the `else` you get very close to what you need. You just need to repeat the input part as well as the console output.

Comment: I assume `userInput` is a typo for `input`, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input;

        Console.WriteLine("Type in some text: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        while(input.Any(char.IsDigit))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please type in some text without numbers");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

you were right - you do need a while loop.

You may also have a bug , in that the text `123kjhasd` would not parse to an int, so would be considered valid.  If you want to check that all of the text is not a number, you can use LINQ, like i did above.

If I misunderstood, and digits and letters combined is okay, then certainly keep your expression:

```
while(int.TryParse(input, out value)
```

Comment: "Please type in some text without numbers" might indicate that the behaviour wasn't a bug, but intended.

Comment: Yes, I could be wrong.  The way it's worded led me to believe he's looking for no numbers.  I'll leave my answer as is unless he clarifies

Comment: sorry for the wording, yes I only want the input to accept characters only

Comment: is it similar if I want to do the opposite? check if its a digit, not text?

Comment: negate it `while(input.All(!char.IsDigit))`

Comment: thank you, but errors - ! operator cannot be applied to operand of type method group?

Comment: while (!input.All(char.IsDigit)) try that

Answer (score 1):

You were close enough and correct about needing a loop.

```
string input;
int value;

while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Type in some text: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!int.TryParse(input, out value))  // TryParse failed, we're good
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Please type in some text without numbers");
}
```